# Why is this None type?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
 def cal(x,y=1)
    s = ''
    for i in range(0,x,y):
       s = s + str(i)
    print(s)
```

from this, x = cal(6) and y = cal(2). Why x and y is Nonetype?

Isn't it should be str since original s ('') is string, and adding up str value?

Comment: No, it shouldn't since you aren't returning anything. Python functions return `None` unless specified otherwise. Assigning to the result of the function call `cal(6)` or `cal(2)` will get you `None`. Use `return` statements.

Comment: Like Jim suggested, since you aren't returning anything, you would get None. Add `return s` at the end of your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could choose to `return s`, but you didn't, so the return value is `None`.